# Combining wide string literal with string macro

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, widestring

I have a macro for a character string as follows:

```
#define APPNAME "MyApp"
```

Now I want to construct a wide string using this macro by doing something like:

```
const wchar_t *AppProgID = APPNAME L".Document";
```

However, this generates a "concatenating mismatched strings" compilation error.

Is there a way to convert the APPNAME macro to a wide string literal?

Comment: Note: C++0x has a new "do the right thing" rule for this case. §2.14.5/13: "If one string literal has no encoding-prefix, it is treated as a string literal of the same encoding-prefix as the other operand."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try

```
#define APPNAME "MyApp"

#define WIDEN2(x) L ## x
#define WIDEN(x) WIDEN2(x)

const wchar_t *AppProgID = WIDEN(APPNAME) L".Document";
```

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if there was a way of doing this without having to define two versions of the macro (wide and non-wide).

Comment: I've updated my answer to have use some common preprocessor technique to deal with strings. You can see more advanced usages if you peek at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Without macros:

```
const wchar_t *AppProgID = L"" APPNAME ".Document";
```