# c++ easy way to convert macro variable to wchar string literal

Tags: c++, macros

In the following example, I would like to remove the `std::wstring(std::widen(...))` part, but the '#' macro only returns a char string literal -- is there any way to accommodate a wchar?

```
#define FOO_MACRO(className)\
struct className##Factory : public OtherClass {\
// does some stuff here\
} className##Factory;\
someMap->add(std::wstring(std::widen(#className), className##Factory)))
```

How would I do the same thing using wchar?

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand what you want to achieve, as I haven't used wchar, but why oh why oh why are you using macros for this?

Comment: The code that you posted does not work like that. It will compile to error: Identifier someText_not_a_string not found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard macro to promote string literal to wchar\_t in VC++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875774/standard-macro-to-promote-string-literal-to-wchar-t-in-vc)

Comment: perhaps I oversimplified what I am trying to accomplish -- i have edited it with more detail.

Comment: One problem is that you seem to be trying to call `std::widen` with two arguments when it only takes one.  Probably your parentheses are in the wrong place.

Comment: corrected... that was a typo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use an `L` prefix on the string literal to make a wchar string literal:

```
#define CAT(A, B)   A##B
#define WSTRING(A)  CAT(L, #A)
```

Comment: ooooh, I'll try that, it looks promising!